# Not able to execute anything after Thread.join()

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been making a mario game and have made good progress. Now I need to switch between worlds. First I stop the thread running my update and draw methods, then I remove everything that is in the world(player , enemies  , grass , etc.) and then I load a new world. Then I try to start the thread again. But for some reason after stopping the thread, nothing is executed after that and it just 'freezes' right there.

```
private synchronized void clearWorld() {
    stop();
    System.out.println("Stopped");
    for(int a = 0 ; a < handler.wall.size() ; a++) handler.wall.remove(handler.wall.get(a));
    for(int b = 0 ; b < handler.creature.size() ; b++) handler.creature.remove(handler.creature.get(b));
    System.out.println("Everything  removed");
}

private synchronized void switchWorld(String path) {
    world = new World(this , path);
    start();
    System.out.println("Thread started");
}
public synchronized void stop() {
    if(!running) return ;
    running = false ;
    try {
        Main.getGame().thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public synchronized void start() {
    if(running) return ;
    running = true ;
    Main.game.thread.start();
}

 public void run() {
    init();
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    final double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    int updates = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while(running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        if(delta >= 1){
            tick();
            updates++;
            delta--;
        }
        render();
        frames++;

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
            if(world.Goombas==getPlayer().gKilled ) {
                clearWorld();
                switchWorld("/pipe_world1.txt");
            }
            timer += 1000;
            System.out.println(updates + " Ticks, Fps " + frames);
            updates = 0;
            frames = 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this helps. "Once a thread stops you cannot restart it" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881714/how-to-start-stop-restart-a-thread-in-java

Comment: But it does not even print stopped ! Look at the clearWorld method

Comment: I suspect you have a deadlock situation. Can you show us a stack dump and have a look at what the threads are doing in your debugger when this happens?

Comment: If your main game thread is just one big loop - it will never stop, you must provide some way for main game thread - so it will know it must stop, then you can wait for it. e.g. `while (!running)` but then running must be `atomic` or `violatile` (don't know what it is exactly in Java)

Comment: Note: when you call `join()` you are holding the lock so no other thread can obtain it.

Comment: BTW if you do `while(running)` and you haven't used `volatile` or `synchronized` the value can be inlined and changing it later will have no effect.

Comment: @ARJAVGARG Sorry, my mistake. I assume that you use thread.stop().

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.join` suspends the calling thread and waits for the target thread to die. What's happening in your code is that the thread that calls `clearWorld` is waiting for the game thread to terminate.

EDIT: After your update I see that it's the game thread itself that is calling `join`. That is guaranteed to cause the call to `join` to block forever. See [Thread join on itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999595/thread-join-on-itself) for an explanation.

Since you're doing everything in one thread there's really no need for the `join` or `start` at all.

If you did have multiple threads, then a better way to do this would be to have a variable in your game thread that checks to see if the game execution is paused. Maybe something like this:

```
class GameThread extends Thread {
    private volatile boolean paused;

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (!paused) {
                executeGameLogic();
            } else {
                // Put something in here so you're not in a tight loop
                // Thread.sleep(1000) would work, but in reality you want
                // to use wait and notify to make this efficient
            }
        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        paused = true;
    }

    public void unpause() {
        paused = false;
    }
}
```

Your `clearWorld` and `switchWorld` methods can then call `pause` and `unpause` on the game thread.